# Trying to determine where error is located

Tags: python, python-2.7

Below is the code I have. When I run it it reports that all are closed which it shouldn't. Can't figure out where the mistake is

```
import datetime
import time
import pytz 

openingtime = ('09:00')
closingtime = ('21:00')

localtime = int(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H"))
localtime = ('US/Pacific')

easterntime = ('US/Eastern')
UKtime = ('Europe/London')

def checktime(localtime):
    bresult = False
    if localtime > openingtime and localtime < closingtime:
        bresult = True

    return bresult

if checktime(localtime) == True:
    print 'The Local Office is Open Now.'
else:
    print 'The Local Office is Closed Now.'

if checktime(easterntime) == True:
    print 'The East Office is Open Now.'
else:
    print 'The East Office is Closed Now.'

if checktime(UKtime) == True:
    print 'The UK Office is Open Now.'
else:
    print 'The UK Office is Closed Now.'
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following lines:

```
localtime = int(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H"))

localtime = ('US/Pacific')
```

The first line sets the localtime variable to be an integer of the current hour. Then the second line overwrites that variable and instead causes it to refer to the string 'US/Pacific'. That string when passed into your `checktime` function will always compare greater than closingtime (which is the string '21:00') so `checktime` will always return False.

Comment: If I remove the localtime = ('US/Pacific') it still tells me that the eastern one is closed which is shouldn't

Comment: You probably shouldn't be comparing the hours as strings and compare them as ints or something..